# Spark JSON DF: Need help masking data frame with a specific attribute and store it as json without changing the structure of the data

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, nested

I have gone through this link: [How to mask columns using Spark 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46331734/how-to-mask-columns-using-spark-2)

It works fine if the data is in flat format, but it fails when we have the data in nested JSON format.

Do we have any example for the same?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Can you share your code and/or your errors your facing.

Comment: I am unable to add the code, but the problem is well explained